# External MouseListener in Java

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener

I have a class to which I want to add a MouseListener as an external class. My MouseListener (MouseControl.java) is the following:

```
public class MouseControl implements MouseListener {

FileGUI fGUI = new FileGUI();

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    fGUI.input.setText(null);
    fGUI.input.grabfocus();
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

However, when I add the MouseControl to the FileGUI class, I get a StackOverflow error in Eclipse.

```
    input.addMouseListener(new MouseControl());
```

"input" is a JTextField.

How can I correctly pass the necessary parameters, so when I perform a mouseClicked event, my "input" does the following?

Comment: Are you sure the error is from this line?..

Comment: Post the error message and stack trace. The error is most likely caused by code that you didn't show us.

Comment: Your code for the listener seems ok.

Comment: fGUI.input.settext(null); what is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this line `FileGUI fGUI = new FileGUI();` in your MouseControl class.

I suspect in your `FileGUI` class's constructor you are trying to create new instance of `MouseControl` and attach as listener, again while creating new instance of `MouseControl`, `MouseControl` again tries to create instance of `FileGUI` and goes recursively until JVM throws a `StackOverflowException`

If this is the case I suggest you to modify constructor of MouseControl to receive an instance of FileGUI class and use that in MouseControl.

Comment: @KarthikKalyanasundaram how can I do this?

Comment: @user2729661 add a constructor in `MouseControl` class which takes `FileGUI` as a parameter and use that `FileGUI` instance in `MouseControl` (for that you can assign the parameter you receive to the `FileGUI` variable you have in `MouseControl`). In `FileGUI` class, in the place where you create instance of `MouseControl` instead of `new MouseControl()` use `new MouseControl(this)`.